# Can't update to Java 8 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'v having a problem with updating JDK to Java 8. When I point the folder to `Java/jre1.8.0_73` and click `OK` when I cehck again it's still Java 7 folder. Why does that happen? Is that a bug of some sort?

[image]

Comment: Did you change JAVA_HOME in your System variables to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`? After installing Java 8, of course..?

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 isn't available in any version of Android prior to N, which is currently just a preview - see the details of its support for Java 8 here (even N doesn't support every Java 8 feature):
https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Keep in mind that Android is *not* just using the standard Java virtual machine. It uses its own virtual machine (Dalvik in 4.4 and earlier versions; Android Runtime - ART - is available as a preview in 4.4 and later became the default virtual machine) and has its own bytecode format: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html

Answer (score 1):

"Android Studio requires JDK 7/JDK 6 so simply You can't use JDK 8 . "

But if you installed it, you can try to change compiler level to 8- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCTyV.png